# Docker container Hornet failed at start after reboot server

Tags: docker-compose, iota

I deployed a IOTA node and it worked for 3 days interrupted. But when I restart my server, the docker container hornet cant start. Could someone help me with this please?

## docker compose down && docker compose pull && docker compose up -d

[+] Running 9/9

✔ Container inx-poi Removed 0.0s

✔ Container inx-dashboard Removed 0.9s

✔ Container inx-mqtt Removed 0.0s

✔ Container inx-participation Removed 0.0s

✔ Container inx-spammer Removed 0.0s

✔ Container inx-indexer Removed 0.0s

✔ Container hornet Removed 0.0s

✔ Container traefik Removed 2.7s

✔ Network node-docker-setup_default Removed 0.4s

[+] Pulling 8/8

✔ inx-indexer Pulled 2.8s

✔ traefik Pulled 2.9s

✔ hornet Pulled 2.8s

✔ inx-dashboard Pulled 2.8s

✔ inx-mqtt Pulled 2.4s

✔ inx-spammer Pulled 2.9s

✔ inx-participation Pulled 2.6s

✔ inx-poi Pulled 2.9s

[+] Running 3/9

⠋ Network node-docker-setup_default Created 6.1s

✔ Container traefik Started 3.3s

✘ Container hornet Error 5.3s

✔ Container inx-dashboard Started 3.9s

⠴ Container inx-indexer Created 4.5s

⠴ Container inx-participation Created 4.5s

⠴ Container inx-poi Created 4.5s

⠴ Container inx-mqtt Created 4.5s

⠧ Container inx-spammer Created 3.7s

dependency failed to start: container hornet exited (2)

I expected the hornet container run as well.